# How to Create a Java Quiz GUI?

Tags: java, flash

I would like to create a quiz for my Java GUI.

I'd like it to display a question on one page, then have a next button which takes the user to another page telling them if that question was correct or not, and if it is correct they can move on to the next question (by clicking another next button) and if they got it wrong, have to go back and answer it again. However I have no clue how to do this!!

So far I have a simple GUI with a welcome page and tabs down the side, one of which includes a quiz. Would it be a better idea to create the quiz in Flash or something and then embed it into my Java application? Or just do the whole thing in Java? I'm really new to java so I'm not at all sure what to do, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I think it will be much easier to have your quiz in java.  You can  create a new page, add radio buttons, check if the correct button was set to True, otherwise, do not display a continue button, instead display a return to quiz button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be best to use just Java. Consider using CardLayout with your GUI to allow swapping questions, or else you can create and modify key components on the fly such as the text displayed by JLabels and JRadioButtons.

Key though before considering any GUI structures  is to first create solid OOPS based non GUI classes to handle your questions. For instance, you may want classes for:

- Question class that holds a question String, a List of possible answer Strings, a correct answer String. This class can randomly order the incorrect and correct answers, can have a method for checking if the answer selected is correct.
- A Test class that holds a collection of questions, that can present questions in random order, that can hold the score obtained.
- A QuestionReaderWriter class that can read and write questions to a text file (you definitely do not want to hard-code the question text).

Comment: thanks so much for your help! i'll look into how to do that then.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of app it would be best to use the language you are more familiar with.
Since this is just a simple display this  then do that there really is nothing very difficult about it.
Personal, I would lean towards Flash as the flash IDE is drag and drop and an experienced flash guru could make this in a few hours. Flash IDE is geared towards this.